# Autocorrelation Function Properties

Tags: statistics, stationary-processes

For what values of $k$ and $N$ can $f(x) = \frac{5-|k|}{A}$ be considered an autocorrelation function? $K$ is the number of autoregressive lags from $k = 0 \ldots \pm N$

Comment: Try to learn a bit of LaTeX. Also, when you ask a question you should also say what are your parameters/variables. What does $k$ and $N$ mean?